# How can I make Go's http.Server exit after being idle for a period of time?

Tags: http, go, systemd

I am writing a web server in Go using the standard library `net/http` package that makes use of systemd socket activation.

I have the basics working such that the server is started the first time a connection is made to the listening socket, and I can perform a graceful shutdown when signalled (i.e. so `systemctl stop` will work without cutting off active requests).

What I would like is for the server to automatically exit when it has been idle for some period of time.  Something like the following:

1. when the last active request completes, start a timer for say 30 seconds.
2. if any new request arrives during that period, stop the timer.
3. if the timer expires, perform a graceful shutdown.

The idea being to release the resources the server was using, in the knowledge that systemd will start us again when a new client turns up.

It's parts (1) and (2) that I'm not sure about.  Ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't involve modifying all the registered handlers too.

Comment: Do ~10MB of RAM (which you still need to have spare - otherwise the daemon won't be able to start) really worth of complexity you're about to bring to your application?

Comment: Speaking of #1 and #2: you may have a "shared" variable that records the time last request was received, then every N seconds you check if that was too long ago. If it was - shutdown the server. It still would be prone of race conditions (when the server does not accept new connections but still serves the already accepted).

Comment: Resource use isn't the only reason I want to shutdown on idle.  In this case, the service runs as a per-user unit, with the executable installed and updated system wide.  The exit-on-idle behaviour is also intended to make ensure old versions eventually get replaced (I can't easily track running instances during upgrades).

Comment: Use [Server.ConnState](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server.ConnState) to count active connections. Set timer on transition to zero. Stop timer on transition from zero to one. Use [Server.Shutdown](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server.Shutdown) to gracefully shutdown the server.

Comment: What have you tried? This should be trivial to implement. You've even explained how. So where is your attempt, and what problem are you facing?

Comment: "I'd like a solution that doesn't involve modifying all the registered handlers" -- Your *http.Server object has a single handler. Put it there, or use a middleware.

Comment: @CeriseLimón: that looks promising.  I hadn't noticed ConnState before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @CeriseLimón's suggestion, the following helper type seems to do the trick:

```
type IdleTracker struct {
    mu     sync.Mutex
    active map[net.Conn]bool
    idle   time.Duration
    timer  *time.Timer
}

func NewIdleTracker(idle time.Duration) *IdleTracker {
    return &IdleTracker{
        active: make(map[net.Conn]bool),
        idle:   idle,
        timer:  time.NewTimer(idle),
    }
}

func (t *IdleTracker) ConnState(conn net.Conn, state http.ConnState) {
    t.mu.Lock()
    defer t.mu.Unlock()

    oldActive := len(t.active)
    switch state {
    case http.StateNew, http.StateActive, http.StateHijacked:
        t.active[conn] = true
        // stop the timer if we transitioned to idle
        if oldActive == 0 {
            t.timer.Stop()
        }
    case http.StateIdle, http.StateClosed:
        delete(t.active, conn)
        // Restart the timer if we've become idle
        if oldActive > 0 && len(t.active) == 0 {
            t.timer.Reset(t.idle)
        }
    }
}

func (t *IdleTracker) Done() <-chan time.Time {
    return t.timer.C
}
```

Assigning its `ConnState` method to the server's `ConnState` member will track whether the server is busy, and signal us when we've been idle for the requested amount of time:

```
idle := NewIdleTracker(5 * time.Second)
server.ConnState = idle.ConnState

go func() {
    <-idle.Done()
    if err := server.Shutdown(context.Background()); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error shutting down: %v\n", err)
    }
}()
```